# Why is variable declaration supposedly redundant here

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have this method:

```
  getRandomKey(){
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.lookup.size);
    let i = 0, k = null;
    for(k of this.lookup.keys()){
      if(i === r) {
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }

    return k;
  }
```

my IDE (Webstorm) says this:

[image]

I have seen thing like that before, I am pretty certain you need to declare the variable k otherwise it will be global, what am I missing here?

Comment: Another way to implement this without that warning would be to use `for (const k of this.lookup.keys()) { if (i === r) { return k; } i++; } return null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare it to avoid an implicit global, but you don't need to initialize it (you don't need to assign it a value).

I guess your IDE has analyzed your code well enough to know that `this.lookup.keys()` has at least one element so `k` will never stay `null`, and there was no point assigning it `null` in the first place; although I don't see that as problematic (What if `this.lookup` is modified in the future to be empty and you want this function to return `null` instead of `undefined` in that case.

It's also possible that your IDE thinks any variable declaration statement that assigns `null` is redundant because it doesn't distinguish between `null` and `undefined`. That would just outright be a bug in the IDE though.

Comment: I wonder - is it really redundant if there are zero keys in the map? if no keys, wouldn't k end up being undefined instead of null?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yeah, that's what the second paragraph says (reread with emphasis on "at least one element")

Comment: I think that depends on other scenarios that it gives this warning. If it does it every time you do something like `let x = null;` no matter where you do it, I would say that is a bug. If it's only in this one spot it might just be doing an advanced analysis to determine that `this.lookup` is not empty. In either case, my advice is to just suppress and ignore this instance of that warning.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, The reason is because the variable is not used before `k of this.lookup.keys()` The IDE looks ahead and sees that it will be assigned to something else and never use the null. you could assign it `1` or anything else and it will show you this debug message if it is not used before you set it to something else.

Comment: @CoryKleiser How do you know it is assigned to anything else? If `this.lookup.keys()` is empty the loop doesn't run, `k` is never assigned a new value and `return k` on line 34 returns `null`. That is different behaviour than returning `undefined`.

Comment: Hmm, That's correct. So it is JetBrains overlooking that `for(k of this.lookup.keys())` is basically a condition in and of itself. Still this is not because of the `null` assignment. It is because of the assignment alone. If he were to use a different value in the `for` loop it'd go away i.e. `for(a of this.lookup.keys())`

Answer (score 1):

It's because your setting `k` to `null` which is redundant replace `k = null;` with `k;` The reason it is redundant is because you don't do anything with k before you change the value to something else. This means you could set k to anything and as long as your changing it (unconditionally) before you actually use it, you will see this debug message.

i.e. In WebStorm:

```
let i = 0, k = null;
for(k of this.lookup.keys()){
      if(i === r) {
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
```

gives:

> Variable initializer is redundant

However,

```
let i = 0, k;
for(k of this.lookup.keys()){
      if(i === r) {
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
```

is all fine.

Comment: I wonder - is it really redundant if there are zero keys in the map? if no keys, wouldn't k end up being undefined instead of null?